# @Parameters getting Skipped, just basic tests

Tags: testng

**Here is my testng.xml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="com.mycompany.app_maven-project_jar_1.0-SNAPSHOT">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="src/main/resources/testng.xml" />
    </suite-files>
    <test name="Regression Tests">
        <parameter name="username" value="rashRodeo"/>
        <parameter name="password" value="rashRodeo@1234"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.maven.regressionTwo.functionalTwo.TestNGTestsTwo">
             <methods>
                 <exclude name="enterSearchTextDTWO" />                     
             </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**here is my @Test using the parameters above:**

```
@Test
@Parameters ({"username","password"})
public void checkForParameters(String username, String password) {

       System.out.println("Username is :"+username+ " Password is: "+password);

}
```

what is wrong here, why it is getting skipped?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to use proper TestNg annotations sequence-

Like this-

```
@Parameters ({"username","password"})
@Test
public void checkForParameters(String username, String password) 
{

       System.out.println("Username is :"+username+ " Password is: "+password);

}
```

It should works ......

Answer (score 0):

If you give the following in the xml it works:

```
    <suite-file path="./testng.xml" />
```

What exactly is the error message you get?

Comment: There is no error, the Test using @Parameters is just skipped.  Even doing this change did not help.

Comment: Sorry here is the error: Parameter 'username' is required by Test on method printParametersFromTestNGXML but has not been marked Optional or defined

Comment: D you have another method called printParametersFromTestNGXML( )? Your checkForParameters( ) method is fine- printParametersFromTestNGXML( ) is where you need to correct parameter sequence.

Comment: Sorry I just renamed the method hence the confusion

Comment: Did the error go away?

Comment: No it did not, renaming the method will not work, guess its problem with my testng.xml

Comment: Based on your error message maybe the @optional in the method might work: public void printParametersFromTestNGXML( @Optional("test") String username, String password)

Comment: Yes optional works, but I want to refer to parameters from testng.xml.  The whole setup seems fine, but still it gives an error, I am unable to get around this.

Comment: Figured it out, was using NetBeans IDE which was not running testng.xml as TestSuite